# Continuously read data from a server in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, server, client, listener

I have my system connected with some server. I am reading data from the server.
But i want to read data continuously from the server.
Here is my code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("169.254.74.65", 7998);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
Byte[] data = new Byte[1024];
String responseData = String.Empty;
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

Can someone tell me the logic where to place the while loop to be able to listen continuously?

Comment: To read _continuously_ you need a loop. But I guess what you want is "continuously _and concurrently_". That is "not blocking your main thread" - so you need either a plain old Thread (or Threadpool, better) or an asynchronous method.

Comment: You need to implement `Long polling`, search around it.

Comment: no no, just main thread. Data stream would be coming from a single ip address.

Answer (score 2):

Just added loop without changing your code:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("169.254.74.65", 7998);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
Byte[] data = new Byte[1024];
String responseData = String.Empty;
Int32 bytes;
while(true) {
    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    if (bytes > 0) {
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
    }
}
stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

This way it will request data from server in main thread infinitely.
Additional improvements might be:

- change loop condition to indicate when you want to stop reading;
- add sleep when no data is available to avoid wasting processor time;
- add error handling;
- rewrite your code using asynchronous methods.

Comment: It works fine but it reads and prints the message from the server thrice (exactly 3 times) and then reads 0 bytes (nothing) for infinite no.of times.

Answer (score 0):

To receive data continuously you actually need to put in some loop.

for example:

```
 private void StartProcessing(Socket serverSocket)
{
    var clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
    StartReceiveing(clientSocket);
}

private void StartReceiveing(Socket clientSocket)
{
    const int maxBufferSize = 1024;

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];

            var bytesRead = clientSocket.Receive(buffer);

            if (ClientIsConnected(clientSocket))
            {
                var actualData = new byte[bytesRead];

                Array.Copy(buffer, actualData, bytesRead);
                OnDataReceived(actualData);
            }
            else
            {
                OnDisconnected(clientSocket);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void OnDisconnected(Socket issuedSocket)
{
    if (issuedSocket != null)
    {
        issuedSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        issuedSocket.Close();

        StartProcessing(listener);
    }
}

private void OnDataReceived(byte[] data)
{
    //do cool things
}

private static bool ClientIsConnected(Socket socket)
{
    return !(socket.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
}
```